# WPF Data Binding to a property of an object in PowerShell

Tags: wpf, powershell, data-binding

I am attempting to create a two-way binding between an object in an observable collection and a WPF form object. This works fine until the property to which I want to bind is a "sub-property" (apologies if my terminology is wrong).

Here's the code:

```
$HashDataContexts = @{}
$FormMain.DataContext = $HashDataContexts

$DGSourceData = @()
$SourceData = @(@("Item One", 1), @("Item Two", 2), @("Item Three", 3))
foreach($SourceItem in $SourceData) {
    $SourceObject = [PSCustomObject]@{
        SubObject = [PSCustomObject]@{
            ItemName = $SourceItem[0]
            ItemCount = $SourceItem[1]
        }
    }
    $DGSourceData += $SourceObject
}
$DataContext = New-Object -TypeName System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection[Object] -ArgumentList (,$DGSourceData)
$HashDataContexts.Add("Grid1",$DataContext)

$DGBinding = New-Object System.Windows.Data.Binding
$DGBinding.Path = "[Grid1.SubObject]"
$DGBinding.Mode = [System.Windows.Data.BindingMode]::TwoWay
[System.Windows.Data.BindingOperations]::SetBinding($DG1,[System.Windows.Controls.DataGrid]::ItemsSourceProperty, $DGBinding)

# Show the window
$FormMain.Dispatcher.InvokeAsync{$FormMain.ShowDialog()}.Wait()
```

The issue is the $DGBinding.Path whereby it doesn't seem possible to use the dotted notation to specify a sub-property. If I create the object without the sub-property, i.e. ItemName and ItemCount are direct properties of $SourceObject and I create the binding using "[Grid1]" only, all is well.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- `"[Grid1.SubObject]"` as the [`Binding.Path`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.data.binding.path) property value won't work as intended, because what is inside `[...]` is *as a whole* considered a dictionary *key* or collection *index*, with no support for accessing *nested properties*.
- While there is a syntax for accessing properties of a collection - `"[Grid1]/SubObject"` - this too will *not* work as intended, as it accesses the collection item that is considered *current* only (defaulting to the *first*), not *all* of them.

  - As a moot aside: Since you're binding to the [`.ItemsSource`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemssource#system-windows-controls-itemscontrol-itemssource) property of a data grid, whatever single property value `"[Grid1]/SubObject"` returns would itself have to implement the [`System.Collections.IEnumerable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Collections.IEnumerable) interface in order to render anything, and a single `[pscustomobject]` instance does *not* implement this interface; if you omitted `[PSCustomObject]` in `SubObject = [PSCustomObject]@{ ... }`, you'd get a [hashtable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Hash_Tables) instead, which *does* implement this interface, resulting in its *key-value pairs* getting treated as the elements of the collection to render in the data grid.

Therefore:

- Use just `'[Grid1]'` as the `.Path` property value (it specifies the `'Grid1'` key of the hashtable stored in `$FormMain.DataContext`):

  ```bash
  $DGBinding.Path = '[Grid1]'
  ```
- Use [member-access enumeration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Member-Access_Enumeration) to populate the observable collection only with the `.SubObject` property values (sub-objects), not its wrapper objects (note the use of a *cast* for concision and syntactic simplicity).

  ```bash
  $DataContext =
    [Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection[Object]] $DGSourceData.SubObject
  ```

---

A **self-contained example** (requires PSv5+) that demonstrates the solution:

```bash
using namespace System.Windows
using namespace System.Windows.Data
using namespace System.Windows.Controls
using namespace System.Windows.Markup
using namespace System.Xml
using namespace System.Collections.ObjectModel
# Note: `using assembly PresentationFramework` works in Windows PowerShell,
#       but seemingly not in PowerShell (Core) as of v7.3.5
Add-Type -AssemblyName PresentationFramework

# Define the XAML document defining the WPF form with a single data grid.
[xml] $xaml = @"
  <Window
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow"
    Height="450" Width="500"
  >
      <Grid>
          <DataGrid x:Name="DataGrid" />
      </Grid>
  </Window>
"@

# Parse the XAML, which returns a [System.Windows.Window] instance.
$FormMain = [XamlReader]::Load([XmlNodeReader] $xaml)

# Define the collection of objects to bind to the data grid.
$dgSourceData =
  foreach ($sourceItem in ("Item One", 1), ("Item Two", 2), ("Item Three", 3)) {
    [PSCustomObject] @{
      SubObject = [PSCustomObject] @{
        ItemName  = $sourceItem[0]
        ItemCount = $sourceItem[1]
      }
    }
  }

# Add an observable collection to a hashtable and assign it
# to $FormMain.DataContext
$FormMain.DataContext =
 @{
   # The collection must *directly* contain the objects to bind, hence the use of .SubObject
   GridDataSource = [ObservableCollection[Object]] $dgSourceData.SubObject
}

# Create a data binding.
$dgBinding = 
  [Binding] @{
    Mode = [BindingMode]::TwoWay
    Path = '[GridDataSource]' # Index into the hashtable stored in $FormMain.DataContext  
  }

# Connect the binding to the data grid's .ItemsSource property
# Note: For troubleshooting, examine the object returned from this call. 
$null = 
  [BindingOperations]::SetBinding(
    $FormMain.FindName('DataGrid'), # the target grid control
    [DataGrid]::ItemsSourceProperty, # what grid property to bind to 
    $dgBinding # the data binding
  )

# Show the window modally.
# You can modify the data in the grid, and it will be reflected in 
# the observable collection, 
$null = $FormMain.ShowDialog()

# Show the potentially modified collection. 
Write-Verbose -Verbose "The potentially modified collection:"
$FormMain.DataContext['GridDataSource']
```

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time. This explanation is very helpful!